# Copy constructor for doubly linked list

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list

I am writing a code for doubly linked list.
Now for copy constructor which is a good way. Just copying pointers of head and tail or copying whole list to new list?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy the whole list.

I'd say one of main purposes of copy-constructor is copying the whole list and make two independent objects.

Copy/Move the whole list to a new list to avoid unintended dangling pointers due to destructing one of copies, unintended modifications and many other problems...
After copy it should have two independent copies.

---

Also, since you have to write a copy-constructor, you should write:

- Destructor
- Copy assignment operator
- Move constructor
- Move assignment operator

Read [Rule of five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). Moreover, you can take advantages of [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom.

Comment: oh.. dangling pointer .. right.. that must be main disadvantage in just copying pointers .. thank you so much.. I will copy whole list to new list .. @M M.

Comment: C++11 has the "rule of five".  (A move constructor and move assignment operator should be implemented as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read more about `move`constructor or `copy` constructor in C++11. For a deep copy, you need to copy the element.

Comment: This answer introduces two tools of C++ but it doesn't address the question.